# Shorten a link?

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink

Let's say I have a links like this:

```
http://mysite.com?i=343435&f=224&u=334
```

and this link is constant (doesn't change - let's imagine it's a posted article), I want this link to be accessible faster by shortening the link and make it like this:

```
http://mysite.com/myarticle
```

How would this be possible? I heard doing something with htaccess can make this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes the receiving page is `/index.php`.  Change to whatever is appropriate.  The result is still transparent to the end user.  That is, the address bar still says `http://example.com/myarticle`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myarticle$ /index.php?i=343435&f=224&u=334 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this one but it did not work. :\

Comment: @Dugi If placing such rule in .htaccess, you need to remove leading slash. Even better -- replace `/myarticle` by `^myarticle$` in the above rule. If still does not work -- you better show real article name then -- maybe it has some special characters in it.